# Редирект wordpress c добавлением каталога

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cms, redirect

Перенёс блог wordpress с my_site.net на my_site.net/blog/ в корне сайта теперь лежит landing page нужен редирект на нужную статью блога по новому адресу. Т.е. если человек пришёл на сайт по ссылке my_site.net/category/projects/... то его нужно перенаправить с добавлением каталога "blog" my_site.net/blog/category/projects/...

Answer (score 1):

В function.php темы добавить:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
  $search = '/category/projects/';
  $replace = '/blog/category/projects/'; 
  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $path = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $pos = strpos($path, $search);
  if ($pos !== false) {
    $path = str_replace($search, $replace, $path);
    wp_redirect( $path , 301 );
    exit;
  }
} );
```